# Deploy with mina and CKEditor - Skipping precompiled gem assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ckeditor

I'm using [mina](https://rubygems.org/gems/mina) to deploy an app that uses [CKEditor](https://rubygems.org/gems/ckeditor). Whenever I make a change to any JavaScript or CSS file, the deploy script automatically precompiles the assets, including running through all the gem assets that haven't changed. With CKEditor there are a ton. Is there a way to skip precompiling gem assets if the gem hasn't changed?

Answer (score 0):

SSH login and navigate to your project folder

```
mkdir shared/tmp/
```

Edit your deploy.rb as following:

```
set :shared_paths, [..., 'tmp']
```

Next time, when you deploy your app, rails will only compile changed assets and save your time.